# Placing two nodes by relative positioning in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw something like this:
[image]

So I did the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (node1) {Long long long box};
\node[draw, below left=of node1] {short} edge[->] (node1);
\node[draw, below right=of node1] {box} edge[->] (node1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then the result is:

[image]

I want to move the two short boxes just under the long box and within the length of the long box. I also like the two arrows straight vertical. How can I do this? I want to use relative positioning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use appropiate anchors and reference points for positioning the nodes. Use *intersection coordinate system* to draw the lines.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] (node1) {Long long long box};
  \node[draw, below=of node1.west, anchor=west] (this node) {short}
      edge[->] (node1.south-|this node);
  \node[draw, below=of node1.east, anchor=east] (this node) {box} 
      edge[->] (node1.south-|this node);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Any idea, how to place the `short` and `box` nodes above the long box?

Comment: @user4514 Do you mean, changing `below` by `above` in the code?